# Trying to implement DTO's and Builder to those DTO: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto

I have a JPA entity User with a u/OneToMany relation to UserStats, I have made DTO's for both of these and have used the Lombok builder annotation. I have updated my controller code to not just pass the JSON request to the service for parsing and constructing a user directly.

Before showing the An established connection was aborted error it was showing a 'Actual list of paramaters do not match for UserDTO: Required: none, Found: 'java.lang.type.string, ..etc'

The JSON request:

```
{username: "ss", name: "Sam", password: "password"}
```

I think it's something to do with the JSON request, while this may have worked for just constructing User objects, I don't know how to send a request capable of becoming a DTO?

UserDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder()
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {

@Autowired
ModelMapper modelMapper;

private String username;

private String password;

private String name;
private String email;
private String location;
private String bio;
private Integer rating;

@JsonIgnore
private Double leaguePoints = 0.00;

//Integer value of the current played games in 1 league, resets to 0 when league is finished.
@JsonIgnore
private Integer currentLeagueGamesPlayed = 0;

//Integer value of the total played games.
@JsonIgnore
private Integer totalGamesPlayed = 0;

@JsonIgnore
String highestAchievedLeagueType = "bronze";


UserStats innerUserStats = new UserStats();
UserStats leagueUserStats = new UserStats();

//array of strings
UserStats[] userStatsArray = {innerUserStats, leagueUserStats};

private List<UserStats> userStats = Arrays.asList(userStatsArray);

}

UserStatsDTO 

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserStatsDTO {

private Integer victories = 0;
private Integer draws = 0;
private Integer defeats = 0;

private Double victoryScore = 0.0;

private boolean isLeagueUserStats;

}
```

User entity:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

private String name;
private String email;
private String location;
private String bio;
private Integer rating;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<UserStats> userStats;


private Double leaguePoints;

//Integer value of the current played games in 1 league, resets to 0 when league is finished.
private Integer currentLeagueGamesPlayed;

//Integer value of the total played games.
private Integer totalGamesPlayed;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private League league;


@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ArchivedLeague> archivedLeagues;


private String highestAchievedLeagueType;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Game> playedGames;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
private Set<Message> sentMessages;
}
```

UserStats entity:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "userStats")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserStats {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userStatsId;

    private Integer victories;
    private Integer draws;
    private Integer defeats;

    private Double victoryScore;


    private boolean isLeagueUserStats;
}
```

USER CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> signUp(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {

            System.out.println(userDTO.getUsername());

            User userRequest = modelMapper.map(userDTO, User.class);

            System.out.println("SIGNED UP USER");

            User user = userService.signUpUser(userRequest);

            UserDTO userResponse = modelMapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);

            return new ResponseEntity<UserDTO>(userResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` will create a constructor for only **required** arguments (with keyword **final**).

`@AllArgsConstructor` will create a constructor for all arguments. Neither of these 2 constructors match the json object for `UserDTO`.

Furthermore most serializing/deserializing frameworks like Jackson that map Json to Java objects require a no argument constructor to instantiate the object before setting the fields. So you should always have `@NoArgsConstructor` for that purpose.

Also in Intellij you can use `Alt + 7` or through `View -> Tool Windows -> Structure` to see the methods that has been generated